# Checking if result is newly created in MongoMapper

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

When using MongoMapper's find_or_create_by_attr method, is it possible to check whether the returned result was found in database or newly created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `MyModel.find_or_initialize_by_attr` then check `my_obj.persisted?` and call `save` if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the MongoMapper source code, I don't really see a way to detect that.  I think that method is used when you do not care whether it's an existing item or a new one.  If you do care, you probably want to separate it into a find_by_attr call, check if it exists, and then call create! if it doesn't.